# Calculate the limit $\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac 1{x^2}-\cot^2x\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

The answer of the given limit is $2/3$, but I cannot reach it. I have tried to use the L'Hospital rule, but I couldn't drive it to the end. Please give a detailed solution!

$$\lim_{x\to 0}  \left(\dfrac 1{x^2}-\cot^2x\right)$$

Comment: What is ctg, and is it being subtracted from $\frac{1}{x^2}$, or is it in the denominator being subtracted from $x^2$? It will also be helpful for you to learn to typeset the math properly, [using Mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?lq=1).

Comment: @pjs36 : $\operatorname{ctg}$ is a somewhat standard alternative to $\cot$. It means the cotangent function. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Since $1/x^2$ and $\cot^2 x$ both go to infinity as $x\to0$, I'd start by finding a common denominator and subtracting the fractions.  They you're working on just one fraction, to which L'Hopital's rule might be applicable. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Im from Romania ,that's why I am using this notation.:)

Comment: Thank you, @MichaelHardy - I learn so much in passing :)

Comment: I have tried bringing to a common denominator and apply L'Hospital,but I got stuck

Comment: @Rori ,it is not the same limit.

Comment: "I have tried to use the L'Hospital rule, but i couldnt drive it to the end" Hence forget LH and *turn to the Light side of the Force*... hrmm, to simpler and more powerful tools... :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a non-series solution.

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2} - \cot^2(x)\right) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x) - x^2\cos^2(x)}{x^2\sin^2(x)}$$

Instead of directly doing l'Hospital, we can make our life easier using $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$ Or rather, $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{x}{\sin(x)} = 1$:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x) - x^2\cos^2(x)}{x^2\sin^2(x)} = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{x}{\sin(x)}\right)^2\left(\frac{\sin^2(x) - x^2\cos^2(x)}{x^4}\right) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x) - x^2\cos^2(x)}{x^4}$$

Now l'Hospital. Note that we can freely factor out constants, and also $\cos(x)$ (as it approaches 1 as $x \rightarrow 0$):

\begin{align*} \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin^2(x) - x^2\cos^2(x)}{x^4} &= \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x) - 2x\cos^2(x) + 2x^2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{4x^3} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\sin(x) - x\cos(x) + x^2\sin(x)}{x^3} \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\cos(x) - \cos(x) + x\sin(x) + 2x\sin(x) + x^2\cos(x)}{3x^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{6}\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{3x\sin(x) + x^2\cos(x)}{x^2} \\
&= \frac{1}{6}\left(\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}3\frac{\sin(x)}{x} + \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \cos(x)\right) \\
&= \frac{1}{6}(3 + 1) = \frac{2}{3}\end{align*}

Comment: I'm a Romanian student as well and judging by the question, the OP must be an 11th or 12th grader at most.  Our system is quite rigid and obsolete, hence using any techniques that weren't taught in class would result in a student getting no credit whatsoever for the solution, no matter how brilliant the ideas in it might be. That said, since they don't teach series expansions in Romanian high schools, this is the solution that fits the OP's needs best.

Comment: @Victor ,I am a 11th grader indeed and this was one of the exercises from my L'Hospital homework.I was doing it just to make sure i cant easily use this rule correctly whenever im in need of it.

Answer (score 7):

One may recall that, as $x \to 0$, we have
$$
\cos x= 1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{24}+O(x^6)
$$
$$
\sin x= x-\frac{x^3}6+\frac{x^5}{120}+O(x^6)
$$ and using
$$
\frac1{1-u}=1+u+u^2+O(u^3), \quad u \to 0,
$$ it gives
$$
\cot x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{3}+O(x^3)
$$ and
$$
\cot^2 x = \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac23+O(x^2)
$$ Thus, as $x \to 0$,

> $$
> \frac{1}{x^2}-\cot^2 x=\color{blue}{\frac23}+O(x^2)
> $$

and the desired limit is $\color{blue}{\dfrac23}$.

Comment: That's the way to go!  L'Hospital's Rule is not always the most efficient and I wonder why asymptotic expansion approach is not emphasized enough in teaching ... +1

Comment: @Dr.MV: Such limit problems are often encountered by students during their first "interaction with calculus" (consider students of age 16-17 yrs) and normally at that stage students (at least in my country India) are not taught about Taylor series. Some books (the ones designed for competitive exams) do offer some techniques like LHR and Taylor, but the standard classroom textbooks don't teach these. I believe teaching such topics without proofs is not a good idea. If most of the limits can be solved by simpler technique, better to avoid advanced techniques in introductory course.

Comment: @paramanandsingh Taylor Series is not a more "advanced" tecnique.  So, I disagree with your premise.  And it certainly is not simpler to use in general.  But I appreciate your comment.  ;-)

Answer (score 5):

We can proceed in the following manner
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}} - \cot^{2}x\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^{2}} - \frac{\cos^{2}x}{\sin^{2}x}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x - x^{2}\cos^{2}x}{x^{2}\sin^{2}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x - x^{2}\cos^{2}x}{x^{4}}\cdot\frac{x^{2}}{\sin^{2}x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin^{2}x - x^{2}\cos^{2}x}{x^{4}}\cdot 1^{2}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^{3}}\cdot\frac{\sin x + x\cos x}{x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^{3}}\cdot\left(\frac{\sin x}{x} + \cos x\right)\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{x^{3}}\notag\\
&= 2\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\cos x - \cos x + x\sin x}{3x^{2}}\text{ (via LHR)}\notag\\
&= \frac{2}{3}\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}\notag\\
&= \frac{2}{3}\notag
\end{align}

As I have told often on MSE, LHR is best used with a combination of standard limits and rules of "algebra of limits". When you have to differentiate too many times in applying LHR its a signal that you are going on a laborious path and perhaps there is a simpler route. The above solution looks a bit long because of detailed steps otherwise its very simple.

Comment: "As I have said often on MSE", it is a pedagogical hazard that LHR has taken such preeminence in some curriculum, this accident has unfortunate mathematical consequences, and, all in all, this "rule" would better be completely forgotten since "a combination of standard limits and rules of algebra of limits" and a few limited expansions are already a vastly more powerful array of tools. It is telling that your solution is entirely logical until its 10th line, but that then it starts to twist and stretch to manage to enter the frame of LHR... +1 from me.

Comment: @Did: It took me sometime to understand your comment. I have updated the solution to make it simpler. And thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to l'Hôpital's rule, consider the Taylor series of $\cot x$:
$$\cot x = \frac1x - \frac13 x - \frac1{45}x^3 - \ldots$$
Therefore,
$$\begin{align}
\cot^2 x &= \frac1{x^2} - \frac23 - \big(\frac2{45} - \frac19\big)x^2 - \ldots\\
&= \frac1{x^2} - \frac23 + \frac1{15}x^2 - \ldots
\end{align}$$
You can now easily take the limit, since the $\frac1{x^2}$ terms will cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

> **Solution by using L-Hospital's rule (no series expansion)** 
>   $$\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\cot^2 x\right)$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{\cos^2 x}{\sin^2x}\right)$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin^2x-x^2\cos^2 x}{x^2\sin^2x}\right)$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin^2x-x^2(1-\sin^2 x)}{x^2\sin^2x}\right)$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin^2x-x^2+x^2\sin^2 x}{x^2\sin^2x}\right)$$ $$=\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2x}+1\right)$$ $$=1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin^2x-x^2}{x^2\sin^2x}\right)$$ Now, using L-Hospital's rule as follows $$1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\sin^2x-x^2)}{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2\sin^2x)}\right)$$ $$=1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin 2x-2x}{x^2\sin 2x+2x\sin^2x}\right)$$ Apply L-H  $$=1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2\cos 2x-2}{2x^2\cos 2x+2x\sin 2x+2x\sin 2x+2\sin^2x}\right)$$ $$=1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2\cos 2x-2}{2x^2\cos 2x+4x\sin 2x+2\sin^2x}\right)$$ Apply L-H $$=1+\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{-4\sin 2x}{-4x^2\sin 2x+4x\cos 2x+8x\cos 2x+4\sin 2x+2\sin 2x}\right)$$ $$=1-4\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\sin 2x}{-4x^2\sin 2x+12x\cos 2x+6\sin 2x}\right)$$ Apply L-H $$=1-4\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{2\cos 2x}{-8x^2\cos 2x-8x\sin 2x-24x\sin 2x+12\cos 2x+12\cos 2x}\right)$$ $$=1-8\lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{\cos 2x}{-8x^2\cos 2x-32x\sin 2x+24\cos 2x}\right)$$ $$=1-8\left(\frac{1}{0-0+24}\right)=1-\frac{8}{24}=1-\frac{1}{3}=\color{blue}{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: "Apply L-H" No thanks. "Apply L-H" No thanks. "Apply L-H" No thanks. "Apply L-H" No thanks.

Comment: @Harish Chandra Rajpoot ,thank you for your answer,but i think you've made a mistake when you calculated the derivtive form of sin^2(x) (when you applied L-H for the first time).I think the correct derivative form would be (sin^2(x))'=2sin(x)*cos(x) as it is a compound function.

Comment: Kindly note that $2\sin x\cos x=\sin 2x$